# Where is Area and Volume statistics tool in ArcMap 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox, 3d-analyst, toolbar, volume

I want to measure surface volume of an area with different Plane Height above reference plane. There should be a tool for statistic calculation but I cannot find it in 3D analyst toolbox. 
Is it exist in GIS 10.1 ? 
Or which tool can help me to measure ?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to reply.

There is [Surface Volume](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q900000027000000) Tool in Arc Toolbox. Using this you can generate area and volume statistics in ArcGIS.

[Arc Toolbox -> 3D Analyst -> Functional Surface -> Surface Volume.]

You can also add the Area and Volume Statistics tool from Customize->Commands->Search for 'Area' (as shown here). Drag this to add in ArcGIS menubar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.Does this have the same functionality as surface volume in ArcScene?